# Magento trace halt/crash after copying Varien_Object to local

Tags: magento, debugging

I'm following Alan Storm's tutorial here:

http://alanstorm.com/magento_varien_object_debugging

and it is working because my Mage::log() is being called.  However, I only get about 5-10 lines as follows:

```
2015-06-09T17:11:55+00:00 DEBUG (7): 192.168.56.1 - Getting the key event on a Varien_Event_Observer
```

(in some it says `event`, in others `object`)

But anyway, after that the page crashes or just goes white, no HTML.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: You have to limit this to a specify object like it is said in on Alan Storm's how-to. The event and object you get there is because you probably have Observer on the pre dispatch of your pages and the blank page is possibly a getSomething to a huge layout or xml configuration which will mage everything hangs.

Comment: I would also recommend to be sure that you are under `Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);` and with `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` (have a look at your index.php`) for those two

Comment: I found that when I just did `Mage::log()` indiscriminately, I would get the blank page, but if I did something like `if($key=='shipping_description')Mage::log()` then it would work.  So, as you guys are probably alluding, probably something to do with overload